# Emit event using NuxtLayout. Vue3 Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to send an event to Nuxt Layout component.

But nothing happens.

A simple console test on the current component works. But the event does not trigger the Parent component function (Layout)

Could anyone help?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Folder Layout Nuxtv3
Default.vue

```
<template>
<slot @opcao-emit="receivedOpcao" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const receivedOpcao = () => {
  console.log('oioi')
}
</script>
```

---

Folder Page
index.vue

```
<template>
<NuxtLayout>
    <el-radio-group v-model="ruleForm.opcao" @change='sentOpcao'>
    <el-radio :label="1">
    <el-radio :label="2">
    </el-radio-group>
</NuxtLayout>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    const emit = defineEmits(['opcao-emit'])
    const sentOpcao = () => {
      emit('opcao-emit', 1)
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your index.vue page, you can emit directly rather than doing it in the script:

```
<el-radio-group v-model="ruleForm.opcao" @change="$emit('opcao-emit')">
```

You can now get rid of the `sentOpcao()` function as it's redundant, and your parent component should receive the emit as expected.

Comment: This worked for my purpose of a general emit, but I believe the original question was in regard to passing an event to the layout through the layout's slot, so I downvoted this answer since it doesn't completely address the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event bus (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/15950, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt)

In `~/plugins/<plugin-name>.ts`:

```
import mitt from 'mitt';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    const emitter = mitt();

    return {
        provide: {
            activeModalsBus: {
                $on: emitter.on,
                $emit: emitter.emit,
            },
        },
    };
});
```

In `.vue` file:

```
const { $activeModalsBus } = useNuxtApp();

$activeModalsBus.$emit('<event-name>', ...);
$activeModalsBus.$on('<event-name>', ...);
```

I named my bus as `activeModalsBus`, but you can name it whatever you want